# How to present rows of data

Tags: html, html-table

I have to present rows of data from database in aspx page. I would have done it this way:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" rules="cols">
<%if(values != null){ %>
    <%for(int i=0;i<values.Length;i++){%>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:60px;">
                <label id="a_<%=i%>"><%=values[i]%></label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:80px;">
                <input type="text" id="b_<%=i%>" onblur="return Validation('b_<%=i%>')" style="width:80px;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:140px;">
                <input type="text" id="c_<%=i%>" style="width:140px;" />
            </td>
         </tr>
    <% } %>
<%} %>
</table>
```

This forms a grid from the values fetched and upon user entering data into the grid I will have to add each line into basket. I am doing that in onblur. 
Is there a better way of doing this? Better way I mean without using for loop. Please note I should access each value in the label in onblur function.

Comment: do you mean you don't want to add onblur event using `for` loop? if so, bing event to parent element will be good

Comment: I dont know if I can avoid onblur, but for sure would like to avoid for loop mainly bcz of how the id's are created. Could you please elaborate on the second part of your comment?

Comment: using jQuery,  `$("input").on("blur", function(){ /*add them into basket*/ });`

Comment: Please note my question is about how to create table/grid/present data in aspx page

Comment: my bad, just want to help you with my frontend mind

Comment: GridView? Repeater? Do you have a DataSource of some sort?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: data is fetched as dataset. I have created GridView from dataset in another instance but I am not sure if I can access each row in the grid to valid user input. Can I? No idea about Repeater. I will look into that. Thank you

Comment: You surely can. Both on client and server side code.

Comment: @jasonslyvia: appreciate your help

Comment: @MelanciaUK: sounds great. Upon clicking add to basket, each row should be examined individually and then add. If so thank you very much. Shall give it a try.